# SOLVED Woocommerce not displaying products in different languages when the query is modified

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

EDIT: Check out the answer below, it was a rather simple solution after all.

I've been dealing with this issue for so long already so i'm hoping somebody could help me out with this.

Basically what i need is to display woocommerce products on a custom page with working categories and filters. I've managed to get categories working on the main language but whenever a category is selected on the second language, the query returins no posts.

Basically what i did is i enabled poduct_cat query variable on a custom shop page by adding the rewrites.

```
// Adding custom query vars for category filtering on outlet products

add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_rewrite' );

function add_custom_rewrite($query){

    $pages = [
        [
            'page' => 'sooduspakkumised',
            'slug' => 'kategooria',
        ],
        [
            'page' => 'special-offers',
            'slug' => 'category'
        ]
    ];

    foreach($pages as $page){ 
        add_rewrite_rule('^'.$page['page'].'/'.$page['slug'].'/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?pagename='.$page['page'].'&product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^'.$page['page'].'/'.$page['slug'].'/(.+?)/?$','index.php?pagename='.$page['page'].'&product_cat=$matches[1]','top');
        
    }
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);

}
```

I also tried with a custom url parameter by modifying the main wp query

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_rewrite' );

function add_custom_rewrite($query){

    $pages = [
        [
            'page' => 'sooduspakkumised',
            'slug' => 'kategooria',
        ],
        [
            'page' => 'special-offers',
            'slug' => 'category'
        ]
    ];
    
    foreach($pages as $page){ 
        add_rewrite_tag('%product_cats%', '([^&]+)');
        add_rewrite_rule('^'.$page['page'].'/'.$page['slug'].'/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$','index.php?pagename='.$page['page'].'&product_cats=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^'.$page['page'].'/'.$page['slug'].'/(.+?)/?$','index.php?pagename='.$page['page'].'&product_cats=$matches[1]','top');
        
    }
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);

}


// Enable category filtering on discounted products

add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){

    if($query->get('meta_query')[0]['key'] == 'onsale' ){
    
        get_query_var('product_cats');
    
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => [get_query_var('product_cats')],
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ));
        //$query->set('suppress_filters', true);
    
    }

});
```

It seems that WPML doesn't even include those ids in the SQL. Not even when all the ids are manually added to tax query. It's like there is a special function somewhere related to product categories / tax queries which strips it out. I looked at the source but i couldn't find anything useful really.

The funny thing is that everything works in the normal setting, when products are displayed on the official categories page...

I can't seem to figure out what else needs to be added to make it work with WPML. I also tried using untranslated slugs, original category ids etc.

I've tried pretty much everything i've found on the internet. I would expect this taxonomy query to work no matter which languge is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found an answer for this issue. The fault was entirely with WPML, I  went through the source of their plugins and found the part where they are editing the **WHERE SQL condition** for wp query.

/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/query-filtering/class-wpml-display-as-translated-tax-query.php line 28

```
/**
 * @param string   $where
 * @param WP_Query $q
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function posts_where_filter( $where, WP_Query $q ) {
    
    if ( $this->is_not_the_default_language() && $this->is_taxonomy_archive( $q ) ) {
        $post_types = $this->get_linked_post_types( $q );
        if ( $this->is_display_as_translated_mode( $post_types ) ) {
            $terms          = $this->find_terms( $where );
            $fallback_terms = $this->get_fallback_terms( $terms );
            $where          = $this->add_fallback_terms_to_where_clause( $where, $fallback_terms, $q );
        }
    }
    
    
    return $where;
}
```

The issue arises because of the condition

```
if ( $this->is_not_the_default_language() && $this->is_taxonomy_archive( $q ) )
```

The reason being, my custom page is not a category nor a taxonomy of any sort so WPML will not go through the process of including fallback ids in the query.

As we can see here, in order for this IF condition to be true one of these must be met.

Line 58

```
/**
 * @param WP_Query $q
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function is_taxonomy_archive( WP_Query $q ) {
    
    return $q->is_archive() && ( $q->is_category() || $q->is_tax() || $q->is_tag() );
 
}
```

**SOLUTION**

So the solution for my particular case would be to modify the default page query so that WPML would recognize it as a taxonomy, so it could add fallback ids to the query that are of "product_cat" taxonomy.

```
// Enable category filtering on discounted products

add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){

    if($query->get('meta_query')[0]['key'] == 'onsale' ){

        $query->is_tax = true;

    }

});
```

It is a rather simple solution but it took me a some time to figure out because of no documentation of it.